# How to check if the value entered by the user is double (C infinite loop problem,with example code)

Tags: c, variables, double, infinite-loop

I wrote a code that requires two nested loops, I tried to create a control mechanism to prevent loops to entering an infinite loop if user enter except two double variable;  but for example if I enter an  char, it is entering infinite loop again. Which part I need to edit?(It will work as long as the user enters two double variables, the program will terminate if the user enters in a different variable type, but it does not end in the following code, it enters an infinite loop) edit1;Thanks to @EugeneSh fixed the first problem of this code(control==scanf("%lf %lf",&a,&b) should be(control=...)Iam controlling control and flag variable twice ,is there any way to do this better?
edit2; when i add if(control==2 &&flag==1) this expression after while(flag==1) this code works without problem,problem is solved.

```
int flag=1;
int control=2;
double a,b;
while(flag==1){
...
    

   while(control==scanf("%lf %lf",&a,&b)){
         if(control==2 &&flag==1){
           ....
           break;
         }
         else{
           flag =0 break;
         }
   }
}
```

Comment: Remove one `=` from the assignment to `control`. Well, I *think* it is supposed to be an assignment. You need to provide [mcve].

Comment: `%d` tells `scanf` to read a decimal numeral into an `int`. Use `%lg` to read a floating-point numeral into a `double`. Include a space before each `%lg` to tell `scanf` to skip white-space characters (including new-line characters) preceding the numeral.

Comment: so sorry @EricPostpischil ı just realized and fixed it,what i want is reading double variable ,not about floating point sir

Comment: @EugeneSh. thank you very much i did not realized that you are right.When I do what you say for the inner loop, it is all right,in my code the inner loop works up to a certain step, then the outer loop comes into play, when I enter a different variable except double, it enters the infinite loop again. What is the part I need to edit in the first loop?

Comment: If the `scanf` fails (does not read and convert the two items requested and return 2), you cannot just loop and call it again. There is some character in the input preventing it from continuing. So you must read at least that character to get it out of the input stream.

Comment: I did not understand what is the meaning of you must read at least that character to get it out of the input stream,to be clear ,could you explain it sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose you type in something like <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> - the input stream will contain the sequence `{'c', '2', '.', '0', '\n'}`.

The `%lf` conversion specifier tells `scanf` to read and discard any leading whitespace, then read up to the next character that is *not* part of a floating-point constant.  The first character it sees is `c`, which is not part of a floating point constant, so it stops reading at that point.  `a` and `b` are not updated, that `'c'` character is *not* removed from the input stream, and `scanf` returns `0` to indicate there were no successful conversions or assignments.

Even better is if you have bad input embedded in good input - if you type in `123c5`, `scanf` will convert and assign `123.0` to `a`, leave `b` unmodified, and return `1`, whereas you'd ideally like to reject the whole thing.

The best way to address this is to abandon `scanf` altogether.  Instead, read the input as *text* using `fgets()` and convert it using `strtod`.  That way you can catch bad input without it leaving crap in the input stream:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define INPUT_SIZE 80 

/**
 * Reads the next two floating point inputs from the specified input stream.
 * Returns the number of valid inputs read and assigned. 
 */
int get_inputs( double *x, double *y, FILE *stream )
{
  char input[INPUT_SIZE];
  double *ptr[2] = {x, y}; 
  size_t i;

  /**
   * Read the next line from the input stream - if there's an error,
   * we return 0.
   */
  if ( !fgets( input, sizeof input, stream ) )
    return 0;

  /**
   * Otherwise, split the input into whitespace-separated tokens,
   * then try to convert each token to a double using strtod.
   */
  char *tok = strtok( input, " \t\n\f" );
  for ( i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
  {
    char *chk;
    
    /**
     * After calling strtod, chk will point to the first character
     * that is not part of a valid floating-point constant.  If this
     * character is not whitespace or 0, then the input is bad and
     * we break out of the loop.
     */
    double tmp = strtod( tok, char &chk );
    if ( !isspace( chk ) && *chk != 0 )
      break;

    /**
     * Write this double value to the appropriate argument - ptr[0]
     * corresponds to x, ptr[1] corresponds to y.  
     */
    *ptr[i] = tmp;
    
    /**
     * Get the next token in the sequence:
     */
    tok = strtok( NULL, " \t\n\f" );
  }
  return i;
}
```

Comment: thank you  but i still dont have any idea about neither pointer or array,that is why i want to do this just with stdio.h

Comment: I did not understand if i type 123c5 part well,why scanf convert this to 123.0 is there any tutorial about this scanf proporties ,@John Bode ,thanks by the way

Comment: @jamesMoriarty: `%lf` tells `scanf` to skip over leading whitespace, then read any characters that are part of a valid floating-point constant, and stop reading at the first character that *isn't* part of a valid floating-point constant.  In `"123c5"`, the characters `'1'`, `'2'` and `'3'` are part of a valid float but `'c'` is not, so `scanf` stops reading after `"123"`, converts that value to `123.0`, and assigns the result to `a`.